# History and early development of Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, math-history

Please provide references (books, articles, websites links, video links) that describe the conceptual development of calculus, complex numbers, group theory, matrix and linear algebra. I am curious to know about how Mathematicians questioned when they started the problem and the subsequent developments

Comment: For calculus, google Newton or Leibniz.

Comment: Which books have you looked at?

Comment: Some help may also be found in these series of lectures (highly recommended, by the way!) https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34B589BE3014EAEB

Comment: @DahnJahn, thanks for these. I was hoping some good lectures on this topic were out there.

Comment: @DahnJahn Thanks a lot for this link. Its useful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Wikipedia ? It contains a wealth of links and information:

- [History of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_calculus)
- [Complex Numbers: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#History)
- [History of Group Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_group_theory)
- [Matrix: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#History)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Mathematical Thought from Ancient to Modern Times, Vol. 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0195061365)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with [The History of the Calculus and Its Conceptual Development](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486605094.html).